# How to integrate elasticsearch with sonata-admin bundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, sonata-admin, elastica, foselasticabundle

Hi everyone I'm using `SonataAdminBundle` and I want to integrate `Elasticsearch` in order to improve performance.

I have setup the elasticsearch and I have configured the fos_elastica.

I have one Entity for testing, and now I want  to use elasticsearch to for search operations instead of `Doctrine`.

This is my configuration :

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    symfony:
        types:
            product:
                persistence:
                    # the driver can be orm, mongodb or phpcr
                    driver: orm
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
                    provider: ~
                    finder: ~
                    listener:
                        logger: true
                        insert: true
                        update: true
                        delete: true
serializer:
    callback_class: FOS\ElasticaBundle\Serializer\Callback
    serializer: jms_serializer
```